# Mumble/Murmur server-side recording

Tags: voip, live-streaming, recording, game-development

We use a Mumble server for Twitch.TV livestreaming and other gaming-related purposes. I'd like to setup a server-side per-user recording. Why, you may ask – the answer is very simple – we produce videos we post on YouTube. We use different computers for Mumble so we can record pure game audio and mix our voices in the video in post.

Is that even possible to do that server-side? Do I need to modify the source code?

Answer (score 3):

Murmur does not decode audio traffic server-side, but only decides which streams should be copied to what other users (among a few other tasks like encryption and stuff, which isn't of any interest in your question's context). Thus recording voice traffic into like some mp3 audio stream is not an easy task to do and would require lot of changes to murmur source code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to run a mumble client instance on the same machine as the server, and use that to record anything. This means that you'd have a bot user idling in the channel.

Comment: That would cause additional load on the server. I want the recording solution to have minimal footprint. I'd like to dump the audio on the disk but don't be fiddling with audio coding/decoding. It's a very limited cpu and memory instance the server is running on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm right now attempting to achieve a listener bot.
i wrote it in python, reusing the frymaster's eve bot.
it's located here : https://github.com/PartiPirate/mumbleBroadcasterBot/blob/master/lib/mumble-bot.py

It's not operational right now, i've commented line 315 what's missing.

If anyone has (or know someone with) strong python skills and fluent with binary data manipulation, that would help to achieve this bot.